# Cannot read property 'whitelist' of undefined when importing ngrx dev tools

Tags: javascript, angular, redux, ngrx, redux-devtools

Importing [ngrx devtools](https://github.com/ngrx/store-devtools) to enable a **debugger** for **chrome** tools results to an **error** below:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'whitelist' of undefined
>       at isFiltered (:1:5016)
>       at Object.x [as send] (:1:74196)
>       at DevtoolsExtension.notify (store-devtools.js:210)
>       at ScanSubscriber.StoreDevtools.liftedAction$.pipe.Object.state [as accumulator] (store-devtools.js:649)
>       at ScanSubscriber._tryNext (scan.js:61)
>       at ScanSubscriber._next (scan.js:54)
>       at ScanSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
>       at WithLatestFromSubscriber._next (withLatestFrom.js:66)
>       at WithLatestFromSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
>       at Notification.observe (Notification.js:15)

This are my versions below of ngrx:

```
 "@ngrx/core": "^1.2.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^6.1.2",
    "@ngrx/store": "^6.1.2",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^6.1.2",
```

and my **angular** and **ionic**

```
 "@angular/animations": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.11",
    "@ionic-native/core": "~4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "~4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "~4.17.0",
```

Whenever I try to import this code below on **app.module** is always shows the error that I displayed on top.

```
 StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({
      maxAge: 15
    }),
```

The error on top refers to this line of code in my **console** on line **210**

```
this.extensionConnection.send(sanitizedAction, sanitizedState);
```

Appreciate if someone could help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53513246/error-typeerror-cannot-read-property-whitelist-of-undefined?noredirect=1#comment93895879_53513246

Comment: OFFICIAL workaround solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53514787/4231054

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Faced the same issue , it works fine in firefox , uninstalled redux dev tools from chrome and then started working (kind of workaround )

Looks like issue with chrome redux dev tools extension .

ref (https://stackoverflow.com/a/53513518/3742158)

Comment: Yep redux dev tool issue

Comment: It is a weird thing because yesterday it wasn't working then I slept at night and then I woke up this morning then suddenly it is now working again. I didn't even uninstall it in the first place and install it again. But now it is working already.

Comment: I had this same issue yesterday. Today i just remove the extension from chrome and install it again. 
Now working fine.

Answer (score 5):

Just to let you know: I had my redux devtools working fine yesterday. My project dependencies are 99% same as yours. Today I face exactly the same issue. The problem is probably with extension. Try to install another version.

There are some issues on github page about 2.16 version.
https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension/issues/589

Answer (score 5):

Update your chrome extension to 2.16.2 => works again :)